# Project on Imputing Weather Data

Tags: java

I keep getting the message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: WeatherInput:
>   method ()V not found

in my client class for this project I'm working on and I'm not sure why, I was wondering if anyone here could see what I'm missing?

Here's my service class:

```
class WeatherInput
{

 private static final String NEWLINE = "\n";
 private double temp;
 private double tempAverage;
 private double tempHigh;
 private double tempLow;
 private double tempHundred;
 public  String newCity = new String();
 public  String city = new String();


public WeatherInput( String city) {
 temp = 0;
 tempAverage = 0;
 tempHigh = 0;
 tempLow = 0;
 tempHundred = 0;
 newCity = city;
}


public void setTemp( double temprature)
{  
    temp = temp;
    } 

        public void tempCalc(String city)
        {
            while(!city.equals("*"))
            {   

            city = newCity;
        }
                while(temp != 0)
                {

                tempAverage = (temp + temp)/2;

                if(tempHigh > temp)

                tempHigh = temp;


                if(tempLow < temp)

                tempLow = temp;

            if(temp > 100)

                tempHundred = temp;

                temp++;
                }
            System.out.print(tempAverage);
            }

        public String printString(){
        return NEWLINE + "Statistics for: " + newCity + "Average: " + tempAverage + "High: " + tempHigh + "Low: " + "Over 100: "
        + tempHundred + NEWLINE;
        }
    }
```

And this is my client:

```
import java.util.*;       //For Scanner and class                    
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Class Name:  KosmowsiProg2
//Description: This class has one method, the main method
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class KosmowskiProg2
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Method Name: main

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //-----------------------Local Constants--------------------------------------


    //-----------------------Local Variables--------------------------------------
        double  newTemp;


    //-----------------------Objects----------------------------------------------
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String city = new String();
        String inputCity = new String();
        WeatherInput input = new WeatherInput();
        WeatherInput input2 = new WeatherInput();


    //---------------------Method Body--------------------------------------------

    System.out.print("Please enter the names of the cities, ending in a *");
    inputCity = scanner.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter the tempratures, ending in a 0");
    newTemp = scanner.nextDouble();


       input.setTemp(newTemp);
        input.tempCalc(inputCity);  




}//End main method


private static void printResults(WeatherInput in){

System.out.print(in.printString()); 
}
}//End class KosmowskiProg2
```

I'm creating a service class that I can then pass to a client class that will read a list of cities that ends in a "*" and then for each city read a list of tempratures that ends with a "0". It then has to calculate the average temperature, highest and lowest, and then output them along with any temperatures over 100. I've talked to my professor and she told me that the solution is a nested while loop, and that the prompts for the final program should be in a separate client class. I also need to output the totals for each category. The thing is, I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to use this service class I've created in the client to get the data I need. My professor can't seem to explain it in a way I can understand, so I'm hoping for some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your service class in a different file, you need to make sure it's declared public.

```
public class WeatherInput
{ 
    ... etc 
}
```

If you don't you may not be able to access the constructor in the other file.

EDIT:  Oh, i just noticed, you don't have a default constructor (one with no arguments), which is why it throws the NoSuchMethodError exception.  Your only constructor needs a city name:

```
public WeatherInput(String city) {
    ... etc
}
```

You'll need to declare your classes after you have the city names:

```
// WeatherInput input = new WeatherInput();
// WeatherInput input2 = new WeatherInput();


//---------------------Method Body--------------------------------------------

System.out.print("Please enter the names of the cities, ending in a *");
inputCity = scanner.next();
System.out.print("Please enter the tempratures, ending in a 0");
newTemp = scanner.nextDouble();

WeatherInput input = new WeatherInput(inputCity);

input.setTemp(newTemp);
input.tempCalc(inputCity);
```

Or create a constructor that doesn't take any arguments:

```
public WeatherInput() {
   temp = 0;
   tempAverage = 0;
   tempHigh = 0;
   tempLow = 0;
   tempHundred = 0;
   newCity = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`WeatherInput` requires a `String` as part of it's constructor...

```
public WeatherInput( String city)
```

But you're trying to insansiate it with out any...

```
WeatherInput input = new WeatherInput(); // This is bad, must have a String value...
```